# canActivate Documentation Example - General Understanding

Tags: angular

Example from https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate#description
There are several things I am struggling with:

1.
the class `Permissions` AND `CanActivateTeam` contain a function called `canActivate`. How is this good practice? It confuses me, especially since we call `this`.`permissions`.`canActivate` inside the `canActivate`(`)` function!

2.
canActivate always returns true. I don't understand why?

```
class UserToken {}
class Permissions {
  canActivate(user: UserToken, id: string): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

@Injectable()
class CanActivateTeam implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private permissions: Permissions, private currentUser: UserToken) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree {
    return this.permissions.canActivate(this.currentUser, route.params.id);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamCmp,
        canActivate: [CanActivateTeam]
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [CanActivateTeam, UserToken, Permissions]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I can't figure an explanation for this part of documentation, I think the description is great but the code snippet is terrible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Permissions` class has a `canActivate` method, but it is a coincidence. They could have called it `foo` : they called it like that because it is clear what it is used for (once you know what `canActivate` means in Angular. In the same way, if you see an `intercept` in a class, chances are that this class is being used in an interceptor.

For the `CanActivateTeam` class, it has a `canActivate` function because it implements the `CanActivate` interface. This is a good practice created by Angular : you should always implement the interfaces corresponding to certain hooks of the framework. This is valid for things such as `HttpInterceptor`, `OnInit`, `AfterViewInit`, etc.

Those interfaces, while not required, are strongly recommended.

2. This is an example of implementation, nothing more. They just give the general syntax, don't expect the API doc to be thorough on examples. It's there to describe the role of a class, and its variables, methods, their types and signatures.

Made it short and simple, `canActivate` should return a boolean, or a promise/observable of a boolean.

If the boolean is truthy, you can access your guarded routes. If not, the navigation is cancelled, and you have to display a message to the user, stating that he can not access this part of your application.

Comment: Isn't it better to create a main guard (implements CanActivate), each time you need to modify the way your guard works for a component, you create a class that extends and overwrite the canActivate method ?

Comment: @Florian you don't extend classes in Angular, you compose ! And no, it's not better, it's personal preference : for me, I would use a provider factory to rewrite my service and inject it the different modules. There's no "best way", there's only good practices, and personal preference !

Comment: hmm interesting, I didn't even think about factory. What do you mean by "you don't extends classes in Angular you compose" ?

Comment: You don't `class X extends Y`, you `class X implements W, Y, Z`. [Angular firebase channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsVL_xrYO0w) has made a very interesting video about that !

Comment: I have created custom field-forms which are components (checkbox, date, input, etc) who all inherit from a general FormFieldComponent. I wonder why you say I shouldn't do that ? Thank you for the the link, I'm going to watch it right now.

Comment: I'm not saying you should not do that, I'm saying that the Angular framework composes and don't extend. It's very rare (I don't even have an example in mind) to see an `extends` when coding with the framework ! Again, it's personal preference, and after you have seen the video, I hope you will understand !

Comment: That's a great video, thank you for sharing. In my formfields case I could completely use mixins pattern !

Answer (score 1):

CanActivateTeam is an implementation of the `CanActivate` Angular Route guards mechanisms.

It is used to to prevent a user to access a route (canActivate) or a group of routes (canActivateChild). It can also be used to resolve data before accessing a route (loading/check auth from webservice)

When you implement the `CanActivate` interface, you have to provide the `canActivate` function that must return either a boolean, a Promise or an Observable.
In the example you had given, an external service is called that is handling that logic. The practice is good as it is always good to separate concers (route guard is one thing, a permission service an other)

Then the `CanActivateTeam::canActivate` method `PermissionService::canActivate` to know if the user can access this route.

In the `PermissionService::canActivate`, it up to you to code your own logic (call a WS, check a cookie, etc), and I guess they put a simple `return true` to not complicate their simple example.